# Spacing of parentheses in pmatrix

Tags: spacing, matrices, arrays, brackets

Commonly, we type matrices as `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}`. However, `pmatrix` is restricted to at most 10 columns. If the matrix has more, we get an error `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`.

As a substitute, I use `\left(\begin{array}{cc...c} ... \end{array}\right)`. But the result is not entirely the same: There is more space right of the opening and left of the closing bracket.

What is the easiest/preferred way to exactly reproduce the `pmatrix` spacing behaviour for matrices with many columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximal number of columns in a `{pmatrix}` is set by the LaTeX counter `\MaxMatrixCols`. You can change its value with `\setcounter`:

`\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}`

In the other side, if you want to have `{array}` with the same spacing as `{pmatrix}`, use `@{}` in the preamble:

`\left(\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)`

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! You show how to fix pmatrix, and also how to reproduce the pmatrix spacing with array.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `+pmatrix` from the (recent) `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
An ordinary \texttt{pmatrix}:
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
A \texttt{+pmatrix} from \texttt{tabularray} package:
\[
\begin{+pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
3 & 2 & 11 & 2 & 31 & 2 & 31 & 2 & 3 & -3 & -4 & 15 \\
2 & -1 & -3 1 & 2 & 3 1 & 2 & 3 1 & 2 & 3 & -3 & 5 & -16\\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]

Note that \texttt{+pmatrix} has a better row spacing compared with \texttt{pmatrix}.
Compare these examples taken from the \texttt{tabularray} package documentation:
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{2}{3} & -\dfrac{1}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} \\
\dfrac{1}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{+pmatrix}
\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{2}{3} & -\dfrac{1}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} \\
\dfrac{1}{3} & -\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{2}{3} \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]

However, if you want the original spacing, you can set it. Compare the followings with the first example of this page.
\[
\begin{+pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -3 \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{+pmatrix}[abovesep=0pt, belowsep=0pt]
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -3 \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this anwer! Those array/matrix/tabular extra packages always give me a bit of a headache, as there are so many of them. Like `tabularray`, `array`, `nicematrix`, `longtable` etc. Not knowing how they interfere with each other, I usually try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: @azimut tabularray is a broad band spectrum remedy: for example it can do breakable tables, so you can replace your longtables with `longtblr` and avoid any risk of interference.

Comment: @azimut Don't worry, it's a common fear among newbies, when you're more experienced you'll be able to fully appreciate it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. This sound interesting, maybe I should look a bit more into `tabularray`. This would be perfect: A single package which provides all features spread out to different packages in a uniform way.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think I'm a newbie. But I'm definitely much more on the "user" than on the "developer" side, I want solutions that work without too much hassle. Also, I'm not generally against extra packages, but the context of arrays has always been a bit of a red rag to me. Too many shortcomings of the original system, and (at least in my experience) often enough only partial or overly technical solutions by extra packages.

Comment: @azimut Sorry, my judgment was based on your reputation points, I didn't mean to offend you. Please excuse me if I did it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX No worries, didn't feel offended at all! You are right, the original matrix row spacing is among the severe shortcomings. TeX is designed to give beautiful results like manual typesetters, and it usually does. Then you type matrices with fractions and the result is hard to believe. Thank you for demonstrating the results of `tabularray`. The matrix with fractions looks **much** better, and maybe I really should look into `tabularray`. Dut I have to say that for the matrix with ordinary numbers I prefer the original spacing over the (unmodified) one, which looks too wide for me.

Comment: @azimut I'm happy, thanks. Yes, for matrix without fraction an ordinary `pmatrix` is quicker.